# Power BI - Numeric Format

Tags: number-formatting, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I would like to know how to change the standard format for numbers in Power BI.

The software I use separates decimals by coma "000.000,00", but the idea is to set that to US format: "000,000.00".

How can I fix that?

Comment: When you click on the column, and then go to the Modeling tab, what do you see next to "Data Type" and "Format"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches to this problem.

If all the data sources you have in the current Power BI file are in the European format, you can set the locale of the file accordingly:

File -> Options and settings -> Options
[image: locale]

Once set, Power BI can identify the format for numbers correctly when you change the data type in Query Editor.
[image: source]
[image: changed type]

---

If you're just catering for a particular data source, you can use the transformation `Replace Values` to swap `.` with `,`, and then change the data type to decimal number afterwards.

[image: replace values]

Comment: Hi @Petter_Mendes Does this help solving the issue after all?